# How to use a pre-populated sqlite database my App in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, mobile, flutter

As the question in the title says.

My database file could be pretty large so I don't want to make copies of it unnecessarily and I certainly don't want to build it in situ.

If the db file is a flutter asset, is there a way for sqlite to access it directly?

I've seen suggestions that I should copy the raw data of the asset into a file and then access it but that is a waste of storage.  Or can I then delete the asset?

Is there a simple way of deploying the database as something other than an asset, ie as a raw file?

Comment: I think copying your asset to the file storage and using that is your best/only option.

Comment: Still looking at flutter, but having solved this for iOS & Android, perhaps this is useful: iOS packages allow an included SQLite db to be opened and used directly in read-only mode. Android packages require copying first, as the db file is streamed from the zipped package. So it depends how Flutter maps to the native package format. You may be able to do what I do with my native apps and use it read-only on iOS and copy for Android after version checking any pre-existing db (see https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Note that SQLite ATTACH works in both scenarios - handy!

Answer (score 21):

iOS (and, I think, Android?) will require you to copy the file into the app's working directory first. This is standard practice, and it's part of working within a protected file system. If somehow it's a deal killer to have copies in both your app bundle (consider this the pristine "master") and app documents folder (the "working copy"), I suppose you could also download it from a server on initial app launch, but... time is money.

It's truly not that big a deal, though. To do so, ensure the file in included in the app bundle via your pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/stored_data.db
```

Then, before opening the database, copy it from the app bundle to your documents directory:

> **Edit:** The following apparently fails to copy large files; see iKK's comment below if you experience such issues, as it looks like he's found a native solution. For smaller files, however, this should work fine.

```
// Create a new file within your document directory (Probably want to check whether it already exists first...)

Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "working_data.db");

ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "stored_data.db"));
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Now that you have the database within your app's document directory, you should be able to open it from the `path.` If you're using the [tekartik/sqflite](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/doc/opening_asset_db.md) package (which is where I originally got these instructions), for instance, you can simply:

```
Database db = await openDatabase(path); // Opens SQL database, working_data.db
```

There's no reason (or ability) to delete the pristine copy from the app bundle (which would alter the original binary -- a *huge* nono). Eventually, the OS itself may end up offloading such dreck to a cloud server or other memory-management service, but that's for the platform to decide.

Comment: nice - but unfortunately `rootBundle.load(join("assets", "mydb.db"));` does not work for large db-files (...i.e. mine is > 665 MB). Is there an alternative except going the path of creating a native plugin for each world ?

Comment: Did solve it finally with a Flutter-plugin that does the large-file-copy natively (in iOS and Android separately) - [see my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203688/3826232) or as @mm2001 mentioned above, [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) might also help...

Comment: Great to know, @iKK. I haven't experienced the large-file issue myself, but your solution looks sound. I've edited my original answer to refer others to your comment. Thanks!